# How do I submit two forms from a single page in adf?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, toplink

I am using ADF to build the front end and Toplink for DB transactions. I wanted to show 2 create forms on a single jspx page. Both the forms are from two different objects i.e it doesn't have a parent child relationship. How can I submit the values of both the forms to the backend when the user clicks on the single submit button using ADF?
Any tutorials or examples would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ADF doesn’t work the way you think it does: each page is a single form.
You may, however use two distinct af:panelFormLayout components that look as two different forms from UI perspective. But an af:button button will submit the the entire page as a single form.
Check some examples of ADF pages. You will see that the structure goes like: `<af:document><af:view><af:form>` ... any other components .

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite the button method to call the two methods you want it to execute.
Here are the basics of how to overwrite a declarative button:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/doing-two-declarative-operations-with-one-button